# calling destroyApp(true) from within a lwuit Form

Tags: java-me, lwuit, midp

I want to close a running midlet. But the current item on Display is a lwuit Form. How can I close the app by clicking a Command added to an lwuit Form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pass midlet instance and call `destroyApp(...)` or use `notifyDestroyed();`.

For example,

**Sample.java**

```
public class Sample extends MIDlet {

public Sample() {

  // do something
  new Sample1(this); // pass the MIDlet to another class.
 }
}
```

---

**Sample1.java**

```
public class Sample1 {
public Sample1(final MIDlet midlet) {

  // do something
  Command exitCmd = new Command("Exit") {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                midlat.notifyDestroyed();
            }
        };
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. It worked. I think though there's a typo on the line: midlat.notifyDestroyed(); It is a reference to the final MIDlet 'midlet' parameter in the constructor. destroyApp(true) did not work: There's an access privilege error. So I used notifyDestroyed(); Thanks